# how to call onclick buttons inside my method in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am coming to an issue where I want to get the onclick source image name to show into my database. However, in my `getSourceImageAndStoreToDB` method I can only do one button as shown below. But, I want to achieve if the user selects another button in the carousel. That code below it only gets the first button source image only. Can anyone help me solve this? thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
    void start() { 
        Button btn = ImageButton1.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn1 = ImageButton2.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn1.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn2 = ImageButton3.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn2.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn3 = ImageButton4.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn3.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn4 = ImageButton5.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn4.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn5 = ImageButton6.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn5.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn6 = ImageButton7.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn6.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn7 = ImageButton8.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn7.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn8 = ImageButton9.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn8.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn9 = ImageButton10.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn9.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn10 = ImageButton11.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn10.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn11 = ImageButton12.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn11.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn12 = ImageButton13.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn12.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn13 = ImageButton14.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn13.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn14 = ImageButton15.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn14.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn15 = ImageButton16.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn15.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn16 = ImageButton17.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn16.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn17 = ImageButton18.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn17.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn18 = ImageButton19.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn18.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn19 = ImageButton20.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn19.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn20 = ImageButton21.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn20.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn21 = ImageButton22.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn21.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn22 = ImageButton23.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn22.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn23 = ImageButton24.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn23.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn24 = ImageButton25.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn24.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn25 = ImageButton26.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn25.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn26 = ImageButton27.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn26.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn27 = ImageButton28.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn27.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        Button btn28 = ImageButton29.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn28.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log ("You have clicked the button!");

    }

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter buttonName to the method TaskOnClick() and pass that parameter in the click handler:

```
void start() {
    Button btn = ImageButton1.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(() => TaskOnClick(btn.Name)); // or TaskOnClick(ImageButton1.Name)
}

void TaskOnClick(string buttonName)
{
    Debug.Log ($"You have clicked the button {buttonName}");
}
```

Alternatively, instead of name, you can pass ImageButton or Button to the click handler:

```
void start() {
    Button btn = ImageButton1.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(() => TaskOnClick(btn)); 
}

void TaskOnClick(Button button)
{
    Debug.Log ($"You have clicked the button {button.Name}");
}
```

Comment: Can I not get the first button though. Whenever the user clicks on any button then it give that particular source image name?

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is I have a carousel view that shows buttons and that button(s) have source image, and I just want to get that source image based on the click the user clicks on.

Comment: any solution to the issue I am having?

Comment: your code is not working the way I wanted? please advice.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to load image when user clicks ImageButton (in that case TaskOnClick() should get ImageUrl out of Button/ImageButton it receives and load it) or something else.

Comment: its something else. Basically, I have 29 button images, when I click multiple buttons and click on submit I want to get the source image of them displayed

Comment: Then you need to do following things:
1. In TaskOnClick(ImageButton button), take image (button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite.name) and add it to page's ViewState (for example use List<string> to store selected images) 
2. On submit, get saved images out of ViewState and load them as per deleted code fragment.